# Casting an Object to List<String>

Tags: java, lambda

I have a `Map<String,Object>` which contains an element value of `List<String>`

Now I need to filter the latter and retrieve first value that contains `@`.

The best I did was:

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("alias", List.of("Mxxx", "fstarred@mymail.org"));

    final Object obj = map.get("alias");
    final List lst = (List) obj;
    final Object output= lst.stream()
            .filter(o -> ((String) o).contains("@"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

however looks to much verbose and mostly requires:

1. a final cast to String of output
2. a cast for each object passed into filter

For the above issued, I tried `.map(String.class::cast)`

1. After `lst.stream()`
2. After `filter(o -> ((String) o).contains("@"))`

None of these approaches did work.

Any hints?

Comment: [Never use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) like `List`, as it messes everything up. Cast to `List<String>` (which won't actually verify anything, it's an unchecked cast, but it will make your life easier).

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, don't use raw types. Here is the approach you should use.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("alias", List.of("Mxxx", "fstarred@mymail.org"));

List<String> list = map.get("alias");

String output= list.stream()
         .filter(o ->o.contains("@"))
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(null);

System.out.println(output);
```

Prints

```
fstarred@mymail.org
```